# how can i condense my XML and Java code to make my app run smoother

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made an app that is for my Facebook group. The XML uses a lot of navigation drawers, `WebView`, `ListView`  and the Java uses a lot of adapters to run the listviews. what I want to know is there a way of condensing my code to make the app run better. I have added a snippet of the XML and java for you to look at. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

This a bit of the java code it repeats for every array adapter and I have a few as you can see.

```
 ListView CastingAppsDlNav,FireStickDlNav,RootingToolsDlNav,ModdingToolsDlNav,LauncherDlNav,FlimnTvDlNav,ShowBoxDlNav,
            KodiDlNav,LiveTvDlNav,MediaPlayerDlNav,MxPlayerNav,CodecNav,MusicAppNav,MusicDlAppsNav,AnimeNav,TvGuideDlsNav;

    ArrayAdapter<String> CastingAdapter,FireStickAdapter,RootingToolAdapter,ModdingToolsAdapter,LauncherAdapter,FilmnTvappAdapter,
            ShowBoxAdapter,KodiDlAdapter,LiveTvAdapter,MediaPlayerAdapter, MxPlayerAdapter, CodecAdapter, MusicAppsAdapter, MusicDlAppsAdapter,
    AnimeAdapter,TvGuidesAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_downloads);

        DownloadDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DownloadDrawer);
        SvDownloads = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SvDownloads);
        SvDownloads.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        // Tv Guide Array setup
        TvGuideDlsNav = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TvGuideDlsNav);
        TvGuideDlsNav.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        String[] TvGuideArray = {"Sky+ Tv Guide", "TvGuide.co.uk","Tv Shows Favs","Tv ShowTimes","HomeScreen"};
        TvGuidesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TvGuideArray);
        TvGuideDlsNav.setAdapter(TvGuidesAdapter);
        TvGuideDlsNav.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        //Sky Plus
                        Intent iSkyplusH20 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(SkyplusplayDl));
                        startActivity(iSkyplusH20);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        //Tvguide.co.uk
                        Intent iTvguidecouk = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(TvGuideUkPlayDl));
                        startActivity(iTvguidecouk);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        //Tv Shows favs
                        Intent iTvshowsFavs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(TvshowsFavPlayDl));
                        startActivity(iTvshowsFavs);

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        //Tv Showtimes
                        Intent iTvShowtimes = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(TVShowtimePlayDl));
                        startActivity(iTvShowtimes);

                        break;

                    case 4:
                        DownloadDrawer.closeDrawer(TvGuideDlsNav);

                        break;

                }
            }
        });
```

Next is my XML which is the main reason I want to condense as it massive.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.harrops.h20droidapp.downloads"
    android:background="@drawable/splashbkground"
    android:id="@+id/DownloadDrawer">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:background="@drawable/h20logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80sp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="H20 Downloads"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/SvDownloads"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/CastingDl"
            android:id="@+id/bCastingAppsDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FireStickDl"
            android:id="@+id/bFireStickDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bCastingAppsDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RootingDl"
            android:id="@+id/bRootingToolsDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bFireStickDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ModdingDl"
            android:id="@+id/bModdingToolsDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bRootingToolsDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LauncherDl"
            android:id="@+id/bLauncherAppDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bRootingToolsDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FilmnTvDl"
            android:id="@+id/bFilmnTvDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bLauncherAppDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LiveTvDl"
            android:id="@+id/bLiveTvDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bFilmnTvDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/MediaplayerDl"
            android:id="@+id/bMediaPlayerDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bLiveTvDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anime Apps"
            android:id="@+id/bAnimeDl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bMediaPlayerDl"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="#4b48ac"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/MusicAppsDl"
                    android:id="@+id/bMusicApps"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bAnimeDl"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="#4b48ac"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tv Guides"
                    android:id="@+id/bTvGuideDl"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bMusicApps"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="#4b48ac"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/homescreenDl"
                    android:id="@+id/bHomescreenDl"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bMusicApps"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="#4b48ac"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/CastingAppsDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/FireStickDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RootingToolsDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ModdingToolsDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LauncherDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/FlimnTvDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LiveTvDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MediaPlayerDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MusicAppNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MemeAppDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ShowBoxDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/KodiDlNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MxPlayerNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MusicDlAppsNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/CodecNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/AnimeNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >
        </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TvGuideDlsNav"
        android:background="#4b48ac"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should definitely break this one activity into many. Too many `ListView`

Comment: Without knowing the flow of your app, it's hard to give specific steps - but it seems like breaking your one big activity in to Fragments could help.  What is the purpose of 17 ListViews?  Could you just use one ListView and change the adapter as needed?  (You're not showing all 17 at once, are you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using Fragments to contain the separate ListViews.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png) is what fragments look like.

Assuming that the other ListViews are have similar functions to TvGuideDlsNav, something like this will probably work around the activity handling all the Views at the same time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="com.yourpackage.AListOfListViews"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- THE LIST TITLES HERE -->

</fragment>

<fragment android:name="com.yourpackage.HereIsAListViewOrActivity"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- LISTVIEW OR ACTIVITY HERE -->
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can have an array of you ListView titles in the first fragment. When the user selects an item, i.e. "TV Guide", the second fragment populates and shows the corresponding ListView. When the user selects an item on the second fragment, the same code that you wrote can handle the OnItemClick.

You can also reuse the second fragment by replacing the ListView fragment with the activity.

See Android documentation for more info on how to implement fragments in Android.

**EDIT:**

To implement fragments, you need to have multiple classes extending the fragment class, each with a layout containing a ListView.

As described in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), your OnItemClick should contain a fragment manager to change fragments:

> For example, here's how you can replace one fragment with another[...]:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

In this case, R.id.fragment_container will be R.id.viewer which holds the second fragment. Also, newFragment will be the fragment class that handles the selected ListView.

Comment: this is what i dont understand. how do i implement each fragment. so lets say i click on the tv guide list view how would i make java understand which fragent to use. sorry to be a pain.

Comment: You need to have a fragment class for each listview and a fragment manager in your OnItemClick. Check out the edited answer

Comment: ok so i figured how to make a fragement. but when i try to add this line of code TvGuidesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TvGuideArray); i get an error. i assume it the this statment. but i dont know what to change it for.

Comment: what is the error? also did you put this line in the fragment or the activity? if it is in the fragment you need to replace "this" with getActivity() to get the context